# How to switch orientations of a bamboo tablet?

Tags: 11.04, wacom, graphics-tablet, bamboo

I have a Bamboo Pen Tablet and I use Ubuntu 11.04, and I just want to ask, how can I switch my tablet orientations.

Answer (score 3):

`xrandr` will only change the orientation of the screen, and not always the orientation of the tablet. For that you need to use `xsetwacom`:

```
xsetwacom stylus rotate ccw
xsetwacom eraser rotate cw
etc...
```

Se the man page for full details: `man xsetwacom`, if you want the changes to be perminant then add the commands to a new file in your home directory called `.xinitrc` and now your settings will load on reboot.